# json_encode returns invalid JSON code

Tags: php, json

I am creating with PHP some JSON-data that seems to be invalid. I'm trying to integrate the google API in my code.

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("mobiledb", $con); 
// The Chart table contains two fields: weekly_task and percentage
// This example will display a pie chart. If you need other charts such as a Bar chart, you will need to modify the code a little to make it work with bar chart and other charts
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `Q1`, `Q2` FROM `table2` WHERE `id`=8710058770");
/*
---------------------------
example data: Table (Chart)
--------------------------
weekly_task     percentage  marks
Sleep           30          60
Watching Movie  40          80
work            44          90
*/
$rows = array();
//flag is not needed
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles
    // Note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage and string will be used for column title
    array('label' => 'id', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Q1', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Q2', 'type' => 'number')
);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $temp = array();
    // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['id']);
    // Values of each slice
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Q1'], 'f' => (int) $r['Q2']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

MY Json Output And check in http://jsonlint.com/

```
   {
cols: [
{
label: "id",
type: "string"
},
{
label: "Q1",
type: "number"
},
{
label: "Q2",
type: "number"
}
],
rows: [
{
c: [
{
v: "8710058770"
},
{
v: 35,
f: 40
}
]
},
{
c: [
{
v: "8710058770"
},
{
v: 60,
f: 70
}
]
},
{
c: [
{
v: "8710058770"
},
{
v: 75,
f: 85
}
]
}
]
}
```

And the error I could see when I validate
**Parse error on line 1:
{    cols: [        {

-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'**

print_r($table) output

```
Array
(
    [cols] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => id
                    [type] => string
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Q1
                    [type] => number
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Q2
                    [type] => number
                )

        )

    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [c] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [v] => 8710058770
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [v] => 35
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [v] => 40
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [c] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [v] => 8710058770
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [v] => 60
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [v] => 70
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [c] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [v] => 8710058770
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [v] => 75
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [v] => 85
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
{"cols":[{"label":"id","type":"string"},{"label":"Q1","type":"number"},{"label":"Q2","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"8710058770"},{"v":35},{"v":40}]},{"c":[{"v":"8710058770"},{"v":60},{"v":70}]},{"c":[{"v":"8710058770"},{"v":75},{"v":85}]}]}
```

Comment: can you paste the resulting JSON code?

Comment: There is no chance that `json_encode` would result in an "invalid JSON format".

Comment: Seeing the invalid json would help, in any case you could start by adding `header("Content-type","application/json");` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: well if that is really the resulting JSON, it misses mostly all the double-quotes around the variable names. Plus as Joe already said, there are spaces befor the JSON code begins what results in an error.

Answer (score 3):

you have some empty space at the beginning of your php file before `<?php` this can cause the output to be miss interpreted. also ensure you have

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

before you echo the json.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue is due to string values don't have quotes.
result should be

```
{
"cols": [{
    "label": "id",
    "type": "string"
},
{
    "label": "Q1",
    "type": "number"
},
{
    "label": "Q2",
    "type": "number"
}],
"rows": [{
    "c": [{
        "v": "8710058770"
    },
    {
        "v": 35,
        "f": 40
    }]
},
{
    "c": [{
        "v": "8710058770"
    },
    {
        "v": 60,
        "f": 70
    }]
},
{
    "c": [{
        "v": "8710058770"
    },
    {
        "v": 75,
        "f": 85
    }]
}]
```

}

Because your key are not enclosed in quotes this is giving error.

Now the problem is why it is not in quotes while it should be.

- Please provide print_r($table) then i can check what is the issue .

Comment: And When I am printing both the outputs I was Json and table (array) I was getting the right output but when I print only json I was getting a an error.